# Conditional Data Merging in Mathematica

Tags: data-structures, merge, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

I need to **merge data from 2 different sources**. The tables below illustrate what I have :

[image]

And the desired Output :

[image]

The idea is:

- Look into the first col. of Table1 (TrialNO)
- Look for it in the first col. of Table2.
- Check that the values in the second col. are equal 
  (in reality those col. won't be located at the same locations in the 2 lists)
- If Check is pass append the values located in col. 3 & 4 (Cond1 & Cond2) to the line in Table2.
- I don't think I will keep the headers in the real structure, so it should not represent an additional problem, but suggestions to deal with headers are welcome (whether to remove them and store them somewhere else or treat them in a special way)

**

### EDIT : Giving precision on the shape of my data & my goals

**

I will give a little background on how I get those data to clarify its shape. I am sure it could be described technically in more accurate way. Please don`t hesitate to correct  me.

**I am recording eye-movements (saccades & fixations) and subjects answer to a task while displaying stimuli on a screen on.**

- Each Trial consist of two consecutive displays of 3 seconds each. It is a 2AFC (Two-alternative forced choice).
- Each display consist of presenting a frame (about 1/4 size of the screen) with 8 shapes in it, displayed on 1 out of 4 quadrants of the screen.
- There is 5 conditions of what the frame itself is made of and thus 10 conditions possible for each trial (1 condition of frame against another without repetition).
- There are 2 measures : The choice of the subject & the eye-movements recorded while looking at the stimuli.

*I get those data from 2 different sources :*

---

- The **"display" machine** which provide

-Trial number/Display number

-Informations about the screen

-Conditions

-Subject Answer

-X & Y coordinate as well as size  of the 11 object composing the stimuli displayed.

***In this Matrix, each row is a Display*** so the DisplayNO Column Would go from 1 to 400 (1,2,3,4,...,400) while the TrialNO Columns actually goes from 1 to 200 (1,1,2,2,..,200,200)
since there is 2 displays per trial.

---

- The **"Eye-Tracking"** machine which provides :

-Some similar info (Display number (1to 400), that will be used to merge the 2, condition number, that can be uses to check the mapping bet. the 2)

Then a massive amount of variables describing the eye-movements :

-Fixations and saccades durations, locations, timing etc. (about 100 columns)

***In this Matrix, each row is a fixation.*** The saccade characteristics are then given in columns (previous and next saccade) And there can be from 1 to 30-50 fixations for each display. As a result, I could have 19 rows of data for the first display and 5 for the second.

---

- The first step is to merge the 2 the 2 data structure to obtain a big one with each rows corresponding to a fixation.
- Will have to do this for every subject then aggregate the subjects data on top of each other.

This is my plan to deal with this monster afterward (And this will explain my needs in the other questions) :

- Extract the Header & columns number.
- Present them by group in nice table form 
  -General Info (Trial ID, Condition, Subject ID...), 
  -Display Info (coordinates of objects on screen), 
  -Fixations info etc...
- Have for each of this variabe a summary of the data type (String, Number, text), the range, how many different values the columns takes and some basic descriptive statistics.
- A system to extract parts of this set conditionally (For Example : Extract the condition number, fixations durations, for chosen display by a particular subject)
  That way I extract some well defined table I then run my analysis on without touching the original data.

If I used my precise situation to present my problem I believe, this could yield to a nice efficient and graphically easy to use tool to deal with a lot of data set in general.

Comment: What do you expect when the check does not pass?  Should a ragged array (rows of differing lengths) be produced, or should a fill such as `Null` be used?

Comment: Also, for optimization it would be helpful to know more about the "shape" of your data.  Is `TrialNO` always in order?  How many different `TrialNO` types may there be?  Can all elements of the table be expressed as machine-size reals (which could make everything faster)?  How many rows and columns is your data likely to have?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : A fill such as Null would be ideal. I could not use the data would the check not pass. I am not sure what "machine-size reals" fully embodies, but TrialNO is most likely to be integers going from 1 to 400. I think I need to tell more about what I am trying to do since all my questions, except for the variables coloring refers to pieces of the program I am trying to write to deal with my Data. I will edit this question soon, trying to give as much and as precise information as I can on both what I have and what I need to be able to do with it. Thanks Dr. !

Comment: 500, since this question already has answers, if you are going to post a lengthy program specification, it may be better to do it in a new question.  On the other hand, a few clarifications to this question could help in refining the answers already given.  The reason I asked about "machine size reals" is that if all of the entries in a rectangular array are standard floats (or integers) then Mathematica can use "packed arrays" which will typically take less memory and be faster, if code is designed with that in mind.

Comment: 500, thanks for all the information.  I am too tired to tackle it now, but I'll work through it later.  I expect you may get some upgraded answers in the mean time.

Comment: Dr. thanks a lot. I will work myself on defining the problem even more precisely in the meantime.

Comment: 500, I have not forgotten about this, but I have been too busy to give it the time that will be required for a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I await a more detailed description of your data for better optimization.

```
checkMerge[src_, trg_, si_, ti_, sp_] :=
 Module[{rls, ext},
  rls = #[[si]] -> #[[sp]] & /@ src;
  AppendTo[rls, _ -> {,}];
  ext = Replace[trg[[All, ti]], Dispatch@rls, 1];
  ArrayFlatten[{{trg, ext}}]
 ]
```

The syntax is:

- `src` = "source" list (data1)
- `trg` = "target" list (data2)
- `si`  = list of indexes from source to compare
- `ti`  = list of indexes from target to compare
- `sp`  = list of indexes from source to append to target

For your example, this would be:

```
checkMerge[data1, data2, {1,2}, {1,2}, {3,4}]
```

---

I had to guess the level of changes to accommodate from:

> (in reality those col. won't be located at the same locations in the 2 lists)

Therefore, this may have too much or too little specificity.

1. At present `sp` must be a list of two indexes (column numbers) just because that made things a little simpler, and I am not sure what you want.  Do you want to specify which elements are taken from `data1` and appended to `data2`, or should it be all elements after the compared ones, or something else?
2. If there are standard values for `si`, `ti`, `sp`, defaults can be added so that you may omit these, unless different values are required.
3. I assumed that it was okay to extend the rows that do not match with `Null` to create a rectangular array; these could be deleted afterward to produce a ragged array, if that is your desire.

Comment: I just realized I called you Dr. many times, sorry for that.
I am experiencing problem applying your code to my data. 
The Columns to be considered in the "Source" data (the one from which we copy the columns) are the No. 1 & 2 which must be respectively compared to No. 13 & 8 in the "Target" data (the one that will become the unified set). Also I would like to copy All the columns but the 2 considered and would not know how to adjust for that.

Comment: I yet tested as if I was trying to just append the 3 & 4 and this is what I did : checkMerge[matlabDataLAEH10, eyelinkDataLAEH10, {1,2}, {13,8}, {3,4}];  However, columns are appended but filled with Null. Could it be that my Lists still have  their Headers ? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @500, being called "Dr.", though highly inaccurate, was amusing.  :-)  My nickname is homage to a television science presenter who made an impact on me as a child.  Regarding the problem, could you upload a sample of the data to your server in Mathematica .m format?  It will be much easier for me to track problems that way.  Once I have it working, I will update my answer to also match your specification of data to append.  Further, I shall still return to the larger problem specification when I can commit more time to it.

Comment: It works now ! It was my fault to not pick the right columns. Would you think about the trick to append the columns header, since those don`t pass the test ? They yet appear as null. But really thank you it seems also a fast method !

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possibility:

```
MergeTables[data1_, data2_, samepos1_, samepos2_] :=
 Cases[data1, 
  x_ :> Block[{y = 
      Cases[data2, z_ /; z[[samepos2]] === x[[samepos1]]]},
    Apply[Sequence, Join[x, Delete[#, Thread[{samepos2}]]] & /@ y]]]
```

Usage:

```
MergeTables[data2, data1, {1, 2}, {1, 2}]
```

Comment: Thank You Sasha ! I will yet leave it unanswered to see alternative proposed but this works very well !

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Sasha is way too cool, I do not even know how it works yet.

Here is my attempt, and being a structural more than functional programmer, I used a Table[] (OMG!) to do it. Well, a Table[] is still sort of on the edge of functional programming :)

(*Here A is data2, and B is data1*)

```
n=Length[A];  m=Length[B];

isMatch[a_,b_] := a[[1]]=== b[[1]]&&a[[2]]===b[[2]]

A[[1]] = A[[1]]~Join~B[[1,3;;-1]]; (*do the header on its own*)

Table[If[ isMatch[B[[i]],A[[j]]], 
          A[[j]] = Join[A[[j]],B[[i,3;;-1]]] 
     ],

     {i,2,m},{j,2,n}        
];

A//TableForm
```

--Nasser

Comment: Thank You Nasser ! Definitely feel Matlab Background there ! I am sure with such code that Sasha provides and thanks to Mathematica wonderful help, we`ll be excellent functional programmer soon !